# CodeIgniter 404

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to codeIgnitor and keep getting the error 404, please advise where am I going wrong, below is my structure and pages.
database name: stoma_store_suppliers , 
Database fields: supplierid, supplier_name, supplier_phone

Models Page:_____________suppliers.php

```
<?php
Class Suppliers extends CI_Model
{
 public function get_suppliers($supplierid) {
if($supplierid != FALSE) {
$query = $this->db->get_where('store_suppliers', array('supplierid'    =>$supplierid));
return $query->row_array();
}
else {
return FALSE;
}
}
}
?>
```

Controllers Page__________
suppliers.php

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH'))exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Suppliers extends CI_Controller {

public function show($supplierid) {
$this->load->model('suppliers');
$store_suppliers = $this->suppliers->get_suppliers($supplierid);
$data['supplier_name'] = $suppliers['supplier_name'];
$data['supplier_phone'] = $suppliers['supplier_phone'];
$this->load->view('index', $data);
}
}
?>
```

Views Page:
index.php

```
<?php print $supplier_name; ?>
<?php print $supplier_phone; ?>
```

Comment: add path of `index.php` placed on view and controller file name should be `Suppliers.php`

Comment: Don't have model name same as controller. Suppliers_model would be better Name you should look at codeigniter phpstyle guide

Comment: Wolfgang, I am not sure what you mean by not having model name same as controller, can you explain, thx?

Comment: @wolfgang1983 means that it is hard to understand exactly what library is being used - makes the code difficult to read. It also makes it easy to make coding mistakes. By adding a `_model` or `_view` to the end of the file and class name it is easy to understand exactly what is being used. It is then understood that without the trailing `_model` or `_view` that it is a controller.

Comment: I'm lazy about typing so I use `_m` for models and `_v` for views.

Comment: The php style guide what I was talking about http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: You also do not need to close your controllers or models with `?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Required things to access any page of codeigniter are:

1. First letter of controller file must be capital like `Suppliers.php`.
2. The first letter of the class definition must match the filename, e.g. for `Suppliers.php` it would be `class Suppliers extends CI_Controller`.
3. If a database is to be used, then the correct connection details must be set in the file `config/database.php`.

Below are the steps to access the any page created in the codeigniter.

1. Write your site domain followed by index.php, e.g. `http://mysitedomain.com/index.php/suppliers`
2. To remove the need for `index.php` in the URL add an .htaccess file at the root folder. [Details here.](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html?highlight=htaccess#removing-the-index-php-file) In that case the URL will be
    `http://mysitedomain.com/`. Now, domain name will get followed by controller name and the function to be accessed, e.g.
    `http://mysitedomain.com/suppliers/show`
3. To pass arguments to a controller using the URL add them after the controller/function segments, e.g. `http://mysitedomain.com/user/show/dede`
4. If a controller has an index function - `public function index(){` - it can be accessed two ways:

   A) `http://mysitedomain.com/suppliers/index`

   B) `http://mysitedomain.com/suppliers`

If `/function/argument` URI segments are not provided after controller name, codeigniter will call `index()` by default.